# Getting local variables

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace, local-variables

When getting a stacktrace as error report from an application that is already deployed, it would be helpful to also get the actual variable values to reconstruct the system's state at the point before the exception was thrown.

Is anything like that feasible in Java and how could one do that?

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you cannot get the local variables in the stacktrace as the output is built from instance of StackTraceElement which only contains, the class, the file, the method and the line number (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html).

Comment: You're right. StackTraceElement on its own doesn't help much. Maybe one could get the thread the exception occurred on and work out the values of the local variables from there...

Comment: I'm afraid it'll be hard. If you catch the exception and manage to get the originating thread you'll be out of the source method. So the local variables will no longer exist. I guess it'll require hook at the JVM level. So may be having a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html may help.

Comment: Yes, that would be an option, although I prefer not to instrument (change) the code at all and would prefer to find a way to "talk" to the VM to get the data I need (if possible at all).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tool:

http://www.chrononsystems.com/

It allows you to keep track of the stack trace with the option to go back in time in the application's timeline. I haven't tried it myself but it looks really promising for the type of situation you are referring to (unexpected Exceptions).

It will be good to hear if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) - you can use debugging tools to view this through the entire execution of the program.

Comment: This is it. Debuggin' the deplyed application (the container should be started with the JPDA configuration) as a remote java application in Eclipse.

Comment: Sadly, the application has most likely already been closed by the time I see the stacktrace...

Answer (score 0):

The only way that's going to happen is if the system state in question is reachable through either variables available higher up in the exception-catching chain, or via the exception object itself (in the case of a custom exception):

```
public class MySpiffyException extends RuntimeException
{
    final private int foo;
    final private String bar;

    public MySpiffyException(String message, int foo, String bar) { 
       super(message); this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar; 
    }
    public MySpiffyException(Throwable cause, int foo, String bar) { 
       super(cause); this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar; 
    }
    public int getFoo() { return this.foo; }
    public String getBar() { return this.bar; }
}

...

public void someCode() {
   ...

   int foo = ...;
   String bar = ...;

   if (foo > 0)
      throw new MySpiffyException(foo, bar);
}
```

Comment: How would that be possible from the exception object?

Comment: Only if the code that threw the exception used an exception type which stored references or values to the local variables.

Comment: e.g. it won't happen in most exceptions, but there's no reason you couldn't use a custom exception that cached local variables and gave you access to them via custom methods.

Comment: Hmmm... that's not really feasible in my case. The very nature of exceptions is that they occur exceptional and especially those that I didn't account for are the ones I would need to know the local variables for. An example would be a NullPointerException in a nested call. It'd be great to see the actual culprit by looking at the local variables and see which one is null.

Comment: Max: then you have to rely on the stack trace, and get into the habit of writing code so there is only one thing going on per line, e.g. not `f.foo(b.bar(b.toString())+"gotcha"+(f.baz()>3?"hi":f.getblap()))`

Comment: Fair enough. That was, however, only an example of 1 thing that could go wrong (and unfortunately, I deal with legacy code)... But many thanks for your comments.