# Can the value of a local variable from a static method be retrieved with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

Is it possible to do this?  For example, what would the contents of `ReflectorClass.getString()` need to be for this code to print the contents of `someString`?

```
public class Start {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String someString = "Hello world!";

    System.out.println(ReflectorClass.getString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. There is even no reliable way to get the names of method parameters (e.g. `args`) which is really a pity.

Comment: @bayou.io That's what I was afraid of :(

Comment: you can't access local variables via reflection.

Comment: @wero I presume that also means there is no other way of accessing them?

Comment: why do you need it, though? what's the use case in your mind?

Comment: @MTCoster you can access them directly :-)

Comment: It's not a serious use case, the program I'm writing is a single class to be loaded into an existing JAR for a challenge. I was just looking for loopholes :p The solution exists within a variable inside the `main` method so extracting it would be faster than calculating it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting local variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620430/getting-local-variables)